# Align two data sets using similar signals

Tags: python, signals, correlation, cross-correlation

I want to import and align two or more data sets.

In general, the data sets will have a common signal like vehicle speed. However sometimes this isn't available and I would have to use signals with an expected correlation (for example mass air flow and RPM. Data sets are coming from various pieces of equipment that are not started/stopped in sync. So:

1. Data sets are of different lengths.
2. Alignment may have to work on signals with vastly different magnitudes.
3. Not always the case but potentially sampling rates can be different.

I haven't written any code yet but I want to try head off problems before I get there. So questions:

1. Do I need to pad data sets so that all the lengths match before starting?
2. Do I need to resample data sets so that all have common time step?
3. How do you handle having to work with two signals that might be vastly different in magnitude? (example I gave, exhaust flow is m3/s, low values often well below 1. RPM is usually 1000s). Is there a normalised cross correlation function?

Comment: You have to coordinate it somehow, if the frequenzy of samples are not the same, and you dont measaure the time, how do you expect to put it together?

Comment: ? I do measure the time, I don't think anywhere in my question I have intimated that I don't know the time step. I have time as a column in each dataset. The datasets will be different lengths that much is certain. They may be different sampling frequencies, though I do try to get 10Hz with all devices if I can.